# Using a NSLock in willSet and didSet

Tags: swift, multithreading

I was wondering if using a **`NSLock`** in the **`willSet`** and **`didSet`** of a property to protect the writing in multiple threads is a viable solution.

Something like:

```
private let lock = NSLock()

private static var cachedUserTokenDetails: UserTokenDetails? {
    willSet {
        lock.lock()
    }
    didSet {
        lock.unlock()
    }
}

class func getUserTokenDetails() -> UserTokenDetails? {
    if cachedUserTokenDetails == nil {
        cachedUserTokenDetails = getUserTokenDetailsFromKeychain()
    }
    return cachedUserTokenDetails
}
```

I think it's safe because `willSet` and `didSet` will always be called, right?

Comment: I don't know if that willSet/didSet locking works, but even it it does, it won't solve the real problem: Between `if cachedUserTokenDetails == nil` and `return cachedUserTokenDetails` another thread might have modified (e.g. nilled) the property.

Comment: Oh, I see. It makes sense. Thank you @MartinR